# How can edit web page content in browsers without textarea or textfield?

Tags: javascript

Is there any javascript solution to show a cursor on pages, move it around with arrow keys, edit directly without switching to a textarea interface? I need javascript to manipulate pages, then pass the modified content to server to save to database.

Comment: There's even an HTML solution [contenteditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, you can set a `contenteditable` flag as a html attribute, which makes text editable in situ.

For example, text written in `<p contenteditable="true"></p>` tags.

Reference [HTML Contenteditable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the contenteditable theme suggested by others, there is a very good tutorial on how to implement some of the more advanced features of this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla)